# How to access the first element of Iterable<DoubleWritable> in Haoop MapReduce using JAVA?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to find Min and Max of a list of values using Hadoop MapReduce, and here is how I implement my Reduce code:
[image]
As you can see, I have no problem with calculating `"avg"`, but for `"min"` and `"max"`, I know that the correct way to do it is to assign `min = "first element of the Iterable<DoubleWritable>"`, and `max = "first element of the Iterable<DoubleWritable>"`. I tried the code, which I already commented out, but they did not work. Therefore, I temporarily assign min and max to a verry large and a very small number.

I would be really thankful if anyone can teach me how to access to the first element of `Iterable<DoubleWritable>`, and assign it to "min" and "max" in this case. For your ready reference, I also paste my code here:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {

            if (this.avg_min_max.equals("avg"))
            {
                double sum = 0;
                int counter = 0;
                for (DoubleWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
                counter = counter + 1;
                }
                result.set(sum/counter);
                context.write(key, result);
            }
            else if (this.avg_min_max.equals("min"))
            {
                //DoubleWritable min = new DoubleWritable(values.get(0));
                double min = 999999999;
                for (DoubleWritable val : values) {
                    if(val.get() < min)
                    {
                        min = val.get();
                    }
                }
                result.set(min);
                context.write(key, result);
            }
            else if (this.avg_min_max.equals("max"))
            {
                //DoubleWritable max = new DoubleWritable(values.get(0));
                double max = -999999999;
                for (DoubleWritable val : values) {
                    if(val.get() > max)
                    {
                        max = val.get();
                    }
                }
                result.set(max);
                context.write(key, result);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The third argument is wrong.\n It has to be 'avg', 'min' or 'max'\n");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the safest and fastest way is to use `-Double.MAX_VALUE` for the max and `Double.MAX_VALUE` for the min, since you donot need to get the iterator twice.
But if you still want to use the first element, you can use it like this:

```
double max = values.iterator().next().get();
```